# Instagram: Graph API does not return id of user who commented

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph v7.0 to access Instagram data. 
I can get comments made on instagram media using the following query:

Request:
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/18132613492054980?fields=id,ig_id,caption,timestamp,owner,username,media_type,permalink,children,comments.limit(100){hidden,id,like_count,media,text,timestamp,user,username},comments_count&access_token

Response:

```
    {
      "id": "18132613492054980",
      "ig_id": "2263043983231761272",
      "caption": "Sprite",
      "timestamp": "2020-03-12T06:51:27+0000",
      "owner": {
                "id": "17841430463493290"
      },
      "username": "jobyjohn123456",
      "media_type": "IMAGE",
      "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B9n8oM7nTt4/",
      "comments": {
                "data": [
                          {
                                    "hidden": false,
                                    "id": "18132938077057326",
                                    "like_count": 0,
                                    "media": {
                                              "id": "18132613492054980"
                                    },
                                    "text": "Nice sprite \u0040yziaf__07",
                                    "timestamp": "2020-03-12T06:52:27+0000",
                                    "username": "zimba_birbal"
                          }
                ]
      },
      "comments_count": 2
}
```

In the response, I do not get the User Id of user who commented. It just includes the username of the commenter.

Though, I pass user in the query, the result does not include it.

Do I need any special permission to get user id of the user who commented in the comment response?

Comment: _“Though, I pass user in the query, the result does not include it.”_ - the documentation for that endpoint explicitly explains under which strictly limited condition you can get the user.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I found it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/comment#reading. It says about user field - "only returned if the user making the query also owns the comment, otherwise, the username field will be included".

I understood, this is some thing that API does not return user id if commented by any other user other than post\media owner. My point is: the username field could also be changed by IG user. I am looking some kind of unique identifier so that we could identify user uniquely in our system.

Would there be any solution for this?

Comment: Doesn‘t look like it, no.

Answer (score 1):

There is Facebook API "[business discovery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/business_discovery)" to get the user details of other Instagram User.

API request:

[https://graph.facebook.com/178430463490?fields=business_discovery.username(user_name_you_wantto_get_its_IgUserId){followers_count,media_count,username,ig_id}](https://graph.facebook.com/178430463490?fields=business_discovery.username(user_name_you_wantto_get_its_IgUserId)%7Bfollowers_count,media_count,username,ig_id%7D)

Response:
[image]

We can pass the user name in that API request, then we will get the Instagram User Id.

The documentation says it has one limitation, this will not work for "age-gated Instagram Business IG Users" but I do not exactly know what it means. When I tested for both older Instagram account and new Instagram account (just recently created account) and this API is returning data for both.

When I tested for private Instagram account, it did not work so it seems this api works only for business account.

[image]

If that api does not work, there is one workaround. The following request help to get User Id using its username but I have not found any API documentation regarding this API. It looks like this is not a standard API and moreover it does not need any token.

https://www.instagram.com/user_name_you_wantto_get_its_IgUserId/?__a=1